# Running a T-SQL job under another user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I cant find my proxy user to "Run as" that user !? I am confused which kind of proxy user is appropriate to run a job with a simple T-SQL command.
(I have created a credential and proxy but cant find it under the "Run as" in my Agent job).Please advise!

Answer (score 3):

There is no *Run As* proxy for T-SQL Job steps in *SQL Server Agent*.  You could upvote this with the chance that one day it will be filled:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/632955/enable-sql-agent-proxies-to-run-t-sql-job-steps

The current way to get a T-SQL command to run with a proxy is to run it as an Operating System Command which does support a proxy user (instead of T-SQL which does not) and run the task either using `SQLCMD.EXE` or `PowerShell` to execute the code.

Answer (score 1):

Put `EXECUTE AS ...` at the start of your script, to impersonate the appropriate login.

Comment: A good solution for some cases. However, this requires impersonation rights for the account running the job. Depending on policy it may not be a sysadmin creating the job so that could be an issue.  Another problem arises if the impersonation needs to use a linked server, which would require mapping the impersonated account to a remote user.